# Loading assembly and running a method

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to load an assembly (`dll-test.dll`), and run the method `GetLabel`:

```
namespace Dlltest.Test
{
    public class Main
    {
        public string GetLabel()
        {
            string test = "TestString";
            return test;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code however I cannot get to run `GetLabel`:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\dll-test.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType();
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var result = type.InvokeMember("GetLabel",
                              BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                              null,
                              obj,
                              null);

MessageBox.Show(result.ToString);
```

It should show a message box with `TestString`.

**Edit**

I eventually made it working with:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\dll-test.dll");
var type = assembly.GetTypes();
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type[0]);

var result = type[0].InvokeMember("GetLabel",
                          BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                          null,
                          obj,
                          null);

MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: That will create an instance of System.Reflection.Assembly and call it's GetGabel method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line

```
Type type = assembly.GetType();
```

you're assigning type of `assembly` variable instead of the type that you want. Try `assembly.GetType(type_name)`. Moreover change "GetGabel" into "GetLabel" :)

Comment: Visual Studio gives me the this error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'` for the messagebox.

Comment: You forgot brackets in `result.ToString()` :)

Comment: Ah thanks! I also edited my main post (complete working code).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("MyType");
if(temp == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
//...
```

Comment: Visual Studio gives me the this error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'` for the messagebox.

Comment: use `MessageBox.Show(result.ToString())` (need to invoke the method, not pass it's "reference"